# Scraping html tables with different number of rows

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull data from this site http://www.citizencorps.fema.gov/cc/CertIndex.do?reportsForState&cert=&state=IN using php. Can anyone please tell me why my code below isn't working. Ideally I want to pull the Name, Point of contact, Phone number, email, and Brief Description if one exists then convert that data into a csv file.

```
<?php
require_once "support/simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.citizencorps.fema.gov/cc/CertIndex.do?reportsForState&cert=&state=IN";

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
$name = $row->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
$poc = $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
$phone = $row->find('td', 2)->plaintext;
$email = $row->find('td', 3)->plaintext;

if(count($row->find('td', 4)->plaintext) > 0) {
    $desc = find('td', 4)->plaintext;
}

print_r($name.'<br/>'. $poc.'<br/>'.$phone.'<br/>'.$email.'<br/>'.$desc);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?

Comment: the code does not run if $name is equal anything other than ('td, 0)